# PCA, SMOTE and cross validation - how to combine them together?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, pca, cross-validation, smote

I was reading a lot recently about PCA and cross validation and it seems that the majority call it malpractice to do PCA before cross validation. I would also like to perform SMOTE, but there is a split between those who perform SMOTE before or after PCA. Yes, i am very confused, but even authors of published papers seem to be confused as well about this (Me being a newbie). Even here (on CrossValidate) there are different answers for the same Q about SMOTE and PCA, and the gist is, see what suits your data.
Anyway, I know how to perform each by it's own, but don't know how to do PCA in each fold, for example in Kfold, or any other cross validation method.

1- Is it possible for someone to share with me how to do PCA inside Kfold? Through a loop or pipeline maybe?

2- I personally have a bipolar opinion on the SMOTE/PCA thing:
a- I think that PCA should be performed before SMOTE so that the dimentionality reduction is done on the main (real) training data before we sample it (In my case upsampling).
b- My other thought on it, is that if you upsample and then perform SMOTE then your dimentionality reduction is based on "non-biased" group sample (where both groups now have same number).
My Q here is, if i CV (cross validated) PCA, can i include SMOTE in the mix?

3- Last Q, I saw a video of a prof. who said that if you test/split your data and then CV PCA on the training set, this is wrong. Since cross validate e.g. Kfold already does the train/test split for you. Is this the case? If so, then how would i eventually select my X_test X_train y_test y_train for further analysis?